# SharePoint and Project server securities/permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

As per my knowledge, SharePoint and Project Server permissions are integrated at a level.
I have documents associated with projects stored in Project work-space. Currently there access is impacted by the SharePoint permissions. But what I want is it should only be impacted by Project Server permissions. How to break that integration.